# Cryptography puzzle found on a website. Solutions to$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 = 2011^{2019} $

Tags: logic, puzzle, information-theory, cryptography, natural-numbers

There are 5 numbers a, b, c, d, and e.
1. How can you calculate the number of combinations that verify the following expression:

The form of the combinations : (a, b, c, d, e);

**$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 = 2011^{2019} $**

Is there a possibility where all the numbers are odd?

In the question they were referring to these five numbers as tuples.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It is impossible for all numbers to be odd, If all $a,b,c,d,e$ are odd, then LHS $\equiv 5 \pmod 8$  which is different from RHS $\equiv 3 \pmod 8$.

Comment: Your question is *very* unclear. Can some of the numbers be equal? Can they be negative? Can they be zero? Is the order relevant?

Comment: you should give the address of the website. Really.

Comment: The keys of a block cipher are 5-tuples (a, b, c, d, e) such that: $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 = 2011^{2019}$

Comment: a. Find a key.
b .Are there any keys such that all the component values are odd numbers?

Comment: This is the formulation from the website. I am sure I translated it correctly.

Comment: This may help. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1920-021-03/S0002-9947-1920-1501144-7/S0002-9947-1920-1501144-7.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi7z_uEuPXkAhWbe30KHZJDDGEQFjAAegQIBhAC&usg=AOvVaw2O9WAvcQadiOkH8WmTNMua